# What's the meaning of python regular expression “\2”

Tags: python, regex

```
from re import match

pattern = r"(.+) \2" ＃Change "\1" to "\2" and Error raised

match = match(pattern, "q q")
if match:
```

### print(1)

```
raise source.error("invalid group reference %d" % group, len(escape) - 1)
```

sre_constants.error: invalid group reference 2 at position 6

---

This is from the official document but I don't understand its meaning. I tried /1 and /2. For /1, it is ok. For /2, error happened.

"\number
    Matches the contents of the group of the same number. "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each set of parentheses is a capturing group. You are only capturing 1 group which you can backreference as `\1` but because you are not capturing a second group, the backreference `\2` fails.

On [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) see "Capturing group" and "Backreference".

Another useful tool for regex is Regex101 which allows you to both test your regex and also provides an explanation of what it is doing. I put your unmodified regex there: https://regex101.com/r/LfJ65s/1/

I put another query that may also be of interest to you at https://regex101.com/r/LfJ65s/2

Here we have the query `(.+) (.+) \2` and two patterns:

This is a match

```
q r r
```

This is not a match

```
q r q
```

But if you change it to `(.+) (.+) \1` the one which is a match will change because we are then asking if the first group repeats (after a second group and the spaces inbetween them). We are able to refer to `\2` now because there are now two capturing groups.

By the way, the query  `(.+) \1` basically asks, are there some characters that repeat the same way with a space inbetween them. Matches would be:

`Wow Wow`
`q q`
`123 123`
`___ ___`
`2;3j34kl+++___ 2;3j34kl+++___`
And even three spaces in a row would match  because the space character repeats with a space inbetween it.

Comment: Thank you, Zev. Could you tell me how to correct the code(not the /2 part)?

Comment: what is your desired result? `q q` matches for `(.+) \1` and your code would print the output `1` if you left it as `\1`

Comment: Many thanks, Zev. I'll follow your instruction to learn the regular expression.

Comment: Sounds good! If you have more questions about this just let me know.